# Rails: ActiveRecord Association returns a nil relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to print all the comments and their associated users for a post on a blog. The comments are passed into the view, and their users_id and posts_id are accessible, but I cannot access their users; comment.user returns nil.

Model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Migration:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :text
      t.references :users
      t.references :posts
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

In the controller:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@comments = Comment.where(posts_id: params[:id]).order(:created_at)
```

In the view:

```
<% @comments.each do |c| %>
  <% c.user.nil? %>
    <p><%=c.text%></p>
    <p><%=c.users_id%></p>
    <p><%=c.posts_id%></p>
  <% else %>
    <p><%=c.text%></p>
    <p><%=c.user.name%></p> #Here is where things would break if I didn't check "c.user.nil?"
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The text and ids for the comments print as expected, but the user is still considered nil. Does anyone know how to access user from within the comment model in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue are the names of the foreign key columns in your database. When declaring a `post` association while explicitly stating the foreign key (you could do this), it's going to look for `post_id` on the model. So, you should either change your column in the DB to `post_id`, or change the association method call to this:

```
belongs_to :post, foreign_key: :posts_id
```

Comment: Thank you, it works by changing the comment migration file to read:
t.references :user
t.references :post

Answer (score 2):

In your controller:

Change:

```
@comments = Comment.where(posts_id: params[:id]).order(:created_at)
```

To:

```
@comments = Comment.where(post_id: params[:id]).order(:created_at)
```

You should have a `post_id` column in your `comments` table in the database. Then, you can have access to the `user` for a given `comment` like this:

```
comment.user
```

and eventually:

```
comment.user.name
```

will work too!

Comment: The column is actually named posts_id; if I change it to post_id I get an SQL "no such column" exception. I think that it _should_ be named post_id, but it isn't, that's just how active record made it.

Comment: You did it wrong by not following the Rails standard convention. You should have `t.references :post` in your migration then active record would add `post_id` column in your `comments` table. Adding `foreign_key: :posts_id` works because you already added the foreign_key `posts_id` which REALLY SHOULD BE `post_id`. Anyways, its your personal choice.

Answer (score 0):

Your migrations does not seems right to complete what **@Jake Shorty** said, I would say When doing :

```
t.references :users
```

Rails will actually transform it such as :

```
t.integer 'users_id'
```

which does not match with the default Rails conventions, so it cannot retrieve the associated user using `user_id` foreign key.

To fix it, you need to either change the migration, or change your model :

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :users_id
end
```